# Can you assist me? I have an attendance spreadsheet in google sheets that needs some formula tweaking

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

For starters here is a sample sheet I have created. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1befqsGQvbPfn0XTGrygLOGcrUIMrICUagJVH0S-2rDw/edit?usp=sharing

My attendance sheet has dates in **row 2** and **Name and Role in column A and B**. I have a formula at the bottom of each column that calculates the total present broken down by role. I also have a formula at the top that displays those totals based on whether or not date matches today. I am trying to eliminate the need for the formula at the bottom as I have to copy it whenever I add a new column. Ideally I want to calculate all of this without the need to update my formula every time I add more dates.

Any help would be so appreciated.

P.S. The formula in C28 isn't needed I was just playing with some ideas.

Comment: I am setting this up to be more autonomous. The less formula copying and updating I have to do the better.

Comment: please post links to other forums where you may have shared this problem when asking for help.  It prevents people from doubling/tripling up their efforts.

Comment: Will do. thanks for the heads up